# Using Bluez, how to select what HCI interface to use?

Tags: bluetooth, raspbian-jessie

I have an external USB Bluetooth 4.0 interface and the built in BT interface.

I would like to configure Bluez to use the external Bluetooth 4.0 interface only (hci1).

I did

```
systemctl stop hciuart
systemctl disable hciuart
```

which appears to work as there is only one HCI interface present.

Is this the proper way or should I do something else?

I remember that there is a way of setting up Bluez to use a specific interface, but I can't remember how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it was easier to remove support for a specific device (in my case the built-in Bluetooth device) using udev.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.